# cmake: add_custom_command / add_custom_target ignoring dependency

Tags: cmake

This may be extremely basic, but it's driving me nuts. Let's say I have a compiler that transforms source into object:

```
compiler source object
```

I want to add cmake rules so this is invoked but only when `source` has changed. All the permutations I have tried either never invoke it, or always do.

I'll leave aside the stuff that does nothing for now. This always invokes it, whether `source` has changed or not:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT object
                   COMMAND compiler source object
                   DEPENDS source)
add_custom_target(my_target ALL DEPENDS object)
```

I know that `add_custom_target` will generate a target that is always out-of-date, and so `my_target` will always be built. But when it chains through to the other rule, it never considers whether `source` is out-of-date; it always builds. I'd expect that `DEPENDS` clause to do the right thing.

What am I misunderstanding? I am using an old version (2.6); is it possible there's a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. It's a quirk of my compiler, which wants to always put `object` in the same directory `source` came from. The example above works fine for in-source builds, but for out-of-source, it is looking for `object` in the wrong place and it's never there. Hammering the compiler to put `object` somewhere explicit will solve this, I think.