# Cmake add_custom_command is never running

Tags: cmake

My question is very similar to [cmake: add_custom_command / add_custom_target ignoring dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127743/cmake-add-custom-command-add-custom-target-ignoring-dependency)

But the answer specified does not solve my issue, and also it is for a newer version of cmake (3.20)

I want some files (shader files) to be copied to the executable directory every time the shader source changes

So I have the following code in cmake:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Shaders.txt
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Actually Copying shaders"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/ $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:Editor>/assets
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Shaders.txt
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets
)

add_custom_target(CopyShaders ALL DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Shaders.txt)
```

Now, as I understand, CopyShaders will always be built (since it is always out of date), but  Shaders.txt should only be built once (after the shader source is changed), after which it is up to date

I'm trying to build the target CopyShaders using `cmake --build build --target CopyShaders`

If I'm using MinGW, then "Actually copying shaders" never gets printed if Shaders.txt is present, even if the assets folder containing the shaders has been modified

If I'm using MSVC, I get the following warning on the terminal:

```
 warning MSB8064: Custom build for item "D:\Acads\Programming\opengl\SummerOfCode\build\CMakeFiles\05fb3856b7a5e1f6ce1ea66ca9091779\Shaders.txt.rule" succeeded, but specified dependency "d:\acads\programming\opengl\summerofcode\editor\assets" does not exist. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly. [D:\Acads\Programming\opengl\SummerOfCode\build\Editor\CopyShaders.vcxproj]
```

Again, I do have the folder existing

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out

DEPENDS should only take as input files, not folders

Replacing it with all the files inside /assets works